# How to consistently tell Windows process architecture

Tags: windows, arm

I am currently writing a function which given a foreign process handle should use Windows API to find out which architecture is be used (x86, x64, arm, arm64). Throught a combination of `GetProcessInformation(ProcessMachineTypeInfo)`, `IsWow64Process2()` and `IsWow64Process()` I am able to query most possible combinations. However, I would like to be able to support all combinations possible on modern windows, starting with the earliest windows 10. A particular problem I have is telling apart x86 and arm applications on 32-bit ARM windows 10. `GetProcessInformation(ProcessMachineTypeInfo)` is not supported on windows 10 at all, and `IsWow64Process2()` and `IsWow64Process()` don't return sensible results in that case either because x86 emulation on arm is not considered WOW.

Is there any way to tell such processes apart using WinAPI on 32-bit windows 10 on ARM?

Comment: In what way is IsWow64Process2() insufficient?

Comment: @Luke It is insufficient because if the process is not running under WOW64 (either 32-bit process on 32-bit windows or 64-bit process on 64 bit windows, regardless of intel/arm processor type between them) then `IsWow64Process2()` will always return `IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_UNKNOWN`. On 32-bit ARM windows 10 this will return `IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_UNKNOWN` for both intel and ARM processes.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I don't have an ARM device readily available for testing. What does Task Manager show? Perhaps it imports an API that we're not aware of (or calls an undocumented function e.g. NtQueryInformationProcess). Worst case scenario you could open the process and read the PE header, though that requires more than just PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION.

Comment: I am not sure how to find out what the task manager does. I think the only way to be sure is to read the PE header then.... :(